# Custom product attribute to multiselect filterable magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

```
 /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'product_ingredients',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => __('Product Ingredients'),
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'source' => '\Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => '',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'position' => 60,
        ]
    );
```

I installed this attribute and need filterable dropdown like category.
Try something like this is product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<field name="product_ingredients">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">\OpsWay\KeyIngredient\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-default</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">conditions</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
</form>
```

Old multiselect attribute still visible and new one not saving selected option.

Need help :)